# Move files from a "Synced Folder" on my computer to a different folder on google drive

Tags: java, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

Hey guys Ive been trying to make a script that will take files from a folder on my computer that is synced to my google drive (shows up under Computers>My Computer) and move them to a folder under My Drive. So far this is what im working with. However, Im getting this error "ReferenceError: "target" is not defined. (line 10, file "Code")".

This is my first time trying to do something like this so I'm not very experience. I'm not sure what I have to change target to. Any advice would be appreciated or if you see anything else wrong with my code that would be helpful too.

Thanks!

```
function copyFilesAndTrash(source_folder, dest_folder) {

  var source_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1N86jGD2EJjbpjdY5TTBAbHDAYLMRdGUe')
  var dest_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1rveHeNuwKxnqWcVv3Da_N-uI_NJV-PpY')
  var files = source_folder.getFiles();

  while (files.hasNext()) {

    var file = files.next();
    file.makeCopy(target).setName(file.getName());
    file.setTrashed(true);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "target" variable is used in file.makeCopy(target), but it is not initialized anywhere in your code.

Likewise, dest_folder is defined but not used anywhere.

Try changing "target" for "dest_folder" as this will most likely correct your code.